# como eu imprimo a menor altura ja lida?

Tags: c

```
int sexo = 1;
float maior=0,menor=0,altura;
int tm = 0, tf = 0, sm = 0, sf =0; 
printf ("O valor 0 encera o programa !!!\n");
    while (sexo!=0){
        printf ("1-Masculino\t2-Feminino\n");
        scanf ("%d", &sexo);
        if (sexo == 1)
        {tm++;
        printf ("altura do Homen: \n");
        scanf ("%f", &altura);}

        if (sexo == 2)
        {tf++;
        printf ("Altura da Mulher: \n");
        scanf ("%f", &altura);}

        if (altura>maior){
        maior=altura;}

        if (altura!=0&&altura<menor){
        menor=altura;}
    }
printf ("Menor altura e: %f\n",menor);
printf ("Maior altura : %f\n",maior);
printf ("Numero total de Homens: %d\n",tm);
printf ("Numero total de Mulheres: %d\n",tf);}
```

Answer (score 1):

A não ser que você considere um valor menor com um número muito grande na inicialização, o que pode não ser boa ideia para alguns casos, a melhor coisa é iniciar a variável para menor altura com a primeira altura que o programa receber caso seu valor seja mesmo que o valor inicial (que considerei 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){

    float altura;
    float maior_altura=0;
    float menor_altura=0;

    int sexo;
    int total_feminino=0;
    int total_masculino=0;

    printf ("Digite '0' para encerrar o programa.\n");

    while ( 1 ) {
        printf ("'1' para Masculino\n'2' para Feminino\n");
        scanf ("%d", &sexo);

        if ( sexo==0 ){
            // sai do laço
            break;
        } else {
            // pega altura
            printf ("Altura: \n");
            scanf ("%f", &altura);

            // processa as entradas
            if ( sexo==1 ){
                total_masculino++;
            } else {
                if ( sexo==2 ){
                    total_feminino++;
                }
            }

            // força a inicialização do menor valor
            if ( menor_altura==0 ){
                menor_altura=altura;
            }

            if ( altura>maior_altura ){
                maior_altura=altura;
            }

            if ( altura<menor_altura ){
                menor_altura=altura;
            }
        }

    }

    printf ("Maior altura registrada = %f\n", maior_altura);
    printf ("Menor altura registrada = %f\n", menor_altura);
    printf ("Total do sexo feminino = %d\n", total_feminino);
    printf ("Total do sexo masculino = %d\n", total_masculino);

    return 0; 
}
```

Dica, não tenha vergonha de usar nomes explícitos para as variáveis, fica mais fácil de ler o código. Aliás, pegando os mesmos comandos que você usei eu simplifiquei a entrada da altura.

Answer (score 0):

Agora que vi que você criou outra thread... Você pode fazer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int sexo = 1;
    float altura, maior = 0, menor;
    int tm = 0, tf = 0, sm = 0, sf =0;   
    int iteracao = 1;

    printf ("O valor 0 encera o programa !!!\n");
    while (sexo!=0) {
        printf ("1-Masculino\t2-Feminino\n");
        scanf ("%d", &sexo);

        if (sexo == 1) {
            tm++;
            printf ("altura do Homen: \n");
            scanf ("%f", &altura);
        }

        if (sexo == 2) {
            tf++;
            printf ("Altura da Mulher: \n");
            scanf ("%f", &altura);
        }

        // Define inicialmente menor como a primeira altura inserida
        if (iteracao == 1) {
            menor = altura
        }

        if (altura < menor) {
            menor = altura
        }

        if (altura > maior) {
            maior = altura;
        }

        iteracao++;

    }
    printf ("Menor altura e: %f\n",menor);
    printf ("Maior altura : %f\n",maior);
    printf ("Numero total de Homens: %d", tm);
    printf ("Numero total de Mulheres: %d", tf);
}
```

Nesse caso precisamos inicialmente definir a primeira altura como o nosso referencial inicial. Posteriormente iremos comparando com os valores inseridos a cada iteração.